# Android. How i can set time with command adb shell input keyevent --longpress 23

Tags: android, shell, key, adb

I try do long click in my app.
And i use command `adb shell input keyevent --longpress 23`
but this command just click on my view
I think i need more time duration
How i can set time duration for this command  `adb shell input keyevent --longpress 23`

Comment: you can use something like https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/examples/helper/swipe changing the points to not move

Comment: its work, but i need press "ok" button

Comment: don't know what you mean, you need ok after the long press?

Comment: i mean, i need long press to button 'OK'
Like a - 1) Down action on button ok 2) wait 3 sec 3) Up action on button 'ok'
Ok button in remote controller it like Enter on keyboard

Comment: If you need to long press on OK, long press on OK, I don't see the problem.

Comment: ok, but default time duration for long press in "adb shell input keyevent --longpress 23" is 1500 sec, i need 3 sec or more, i cant see how i can change default time

Comment: In the swipe example I sent you can set `segment_step` to whatever you want (each one is `5ms`) so you can achive what you want.